# Why are the mkdir() and rmdir() POSIX system calls in different header files?

Tags: c, linux, posix, header-files, system-calls

mkdir() is in `<sys/stat.h>` whereas rmdir() is in `<unistd.h>`. Wouldn't it make more sense to have them in the same header file?

Comment: "historical reasons"

Comment: Why is "through" spelled with an "ough", but "flew" is spelled "ew"?

Comment: Whatever, it's not about the change.  These header files have been around for a long time, if they were changed it would stop thousands of programs from compiling.  Live with it.

Comment: Please explain how would you use the answer to your question – whatever answer you can think of.

Comment: @KubaOber To make it easier to remember and to satisfy my curiosity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is, that with `mkdir(2)` you specify the *permissions* in the second argument:

```
  int mkdir(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
```

These mode-flags and the type `mode_t` are defined in `sys/stat.h` (at least indirectly by including `bits/stat.h` and `bits/types.h` on my system), so it seems appropriate to define mkdir() there, too. Otherwise, including `unistd.h` would lead to an error, since the type `mode_t` is unknown there.

In contrast, `rmdir(2)` doesn't take any arguments besides the filename, so it can remain in `unistd.h`, since there are no other dependencies.

Comment: FYI, headers whose names begin with `bits/` are not meant to be used directly. If you look in `bits/stat.h` for instance you'll see that it begins with an explicit warning to use `sys/stat.h` rather than including it directly.  The POSIX standard says that these flags and types are to be defined by `sys/stat.h` _somehow_; GNU libc splits up the required definitions among several headers so that as much as possible of `sys/stat.h` can be shared among all the supported architectures.  Other C libraries will also split it up but not quite the same way.